# Why couldn't Teela Brown make the same calculation that Louis Wu and Chmeee did?

Tags: larry-niven, the-ringworld-engineers

In Larry Niven's *[The Ringworld Engineers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ringworld_Engineers)*, Louis Wu, Chmeee, and Harkabeeparolyn

> travel to the Ringworld's control center on the Map of Mars in the Ringworld's great ocean, in order to find some way of re-centering the giant structure on its Sun.

But there they run into Teela Brown, who

> remained behind from Louis and Chmeee's last visit to the Ringworld. She's eaten Tree-of -Life root and become a "[protector](https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Protector)".

But it's  weird:

> Protector-Teela tells them that there is a way to save the Ringworld, but doesn't tell them what it is.  She's actually come there to try and stop them.

Teela tells Louis:

> "Furthermore,  there is a solution that does less damage, yet it is too much damage, and I cannot permit it."

> Teela's solution will kill 5% of the Ringworld's population to save the other 95%. That's 1,5 *trillion* sapient humanoids out of 30 trillion. It will be a slow death by radiation.

Although Teela

> Knows it **has** to happen, and drops hints to give Louis a chance to figure it out, she nevertheless makes them fight and kill her in order to gain access to the control room.

Louis and Chmeee's advantage is, as Louis puts it, is that

> Teela is fighting to lose.  One of the many strange compulsions of Protectors forces her to engage in "doublethink" to avert disaster.

Why can't Teela resort to simple utilitarianism?

Comment: ...Because she's not a utilitarian?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Except that she clearly is, only in a twisted and self-defeating way.

Comment: It's an IMO flaw in Niven's writing where he imagines beings with an extreme form of genetic predestination. Cowardly Puppeteers, suicidal Kzin, programmed Protectors -- in the extreme form, none of these are likely to be favorable traits in an intelligent being and would not have evolved.

Comment: @MarkOlson "Louis, no sapient being interrupts a defense mechanism". -The Hindmost. There's some stuff in _Ringworld_ and _RE_ that explains the evolution of  puppeteer behavior in a more nuanced way.

Comment: I'm not sure all the spoiler markup is really necessary.  If I wanted to avoid spoilers for ringworld-engineers, I wouldn't read the question.

Comment: Protectors are constrained via instinct and emotion. Their problem solving abilities serve hardwired biological and pheromone driven goals. Teela Brown clearly sees a solution, but she cannot bring herself to employ it, because she can't kill that many breeders, full stop. Even to save trillions more. Protectors intelligence is for problem solving, not abstract thinking. Only via baroque mental gymnastics can they even operate on higher order concepts than smell of kin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Protectors are psychologically "hardwired" to protect all their offspring at all costs. They make this decision by smell (pheromones). The other inhabitants of the Ringworld would count for Teela's human personality, but not for the protector instincts.

Teela lived with Seeker for two decades in the 5% part of the Ringworld that had to be torched and had a child with him (cf Ringworld's Children). So she could not bring herself to "pull the trigger" even if she made the rational decision that she should.